# Why is my filtration not working in Kotlin on Android RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dagger-hilt

I want to make filtration but it doesn't work and I don't know why? #android #kotlin

#Repository

```
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val rickAndMortyApi: RickAndMortyApi,
) {
    fun getAllCharacters() =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(rickAndMortyApi, null, null) }
        ).liveData

    fun getCharactersbyStatusAndGender(status: String, gender: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(rickAndMortyApi, status, gender) }
        ).liveData

    fun getCharactersByStatus(status: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(rickAndMortyApi, status, null) }
        ).liveData

    fun getCharactersByGender(gender: String) =
        Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { HomeFragmentPagingSource(rickAndMortyApi, null, gender) }
        ).liveData
}
```

#ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: HomeRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

     var test = MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>()


    var filterValue = MutableLiveData<Array<Int>>()

    init {
        filterValue.value = arrayOf(0, 0)
    }

    fun getAllCharacters() {
        val charactersData = repository.getAllCharacters().cachedIn(viewModelScope)

        test = charactersData as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
    }

    fun getByStatusAndGender(status: String, gender: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val charactersData = repository.getCharactersbyStatusAndGender(
                status, gender
            ).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            test = charactersData as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        }
    }

    fun getByStatus(status: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val charactersData =
                repository.getCharactersByStatus(status).cachedIn(viewModelScope)

            test = charactersData as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        }
    }

    fun getByGender(gender: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val charactersData =
                repository.getCharactersByGender(gender).cachedIn(viewModelScope)

            test = charactersData as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Characters>>
        }
    }

}
```

#filter fragment

```
binding.apply {
            btnMakeFilter.setOnClickListener {

                if (chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked()
                        .isNotEmpty() && radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked().isNotEmpty()
                ) {
                    viewModel.getByStatusAndGender(
                        chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked(),
                        radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked(),
                    )
                } else {
                    if (chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked().isNotEmpty()) {
                        viewModel.getByStatus(chipgroupStatus.getTextChipChecked())
                    } else {
                        viewModel.getByGender(radiogroupGender.getTextButtonChecked())
                    }
                }

                viewModel.filterValue.value = arrayOf(
                    chipgroupStatus.checkedChipId, radiogroupGender.checkedRadioButtonId
                )

                findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false)
            }
        }
```

#Home fragment (which i want to show filtered data )

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var homeRvAdapter: HomeRvAdapter
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.getAllCharacters()

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.test.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { allCharactersResponse ->
            homeRvAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, allCharactersResponse)
        }


        setUpHomeRv()
        initAdapter()

        binding.filterIv.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_filterFragment)
        }

    }

    private fun initAdapter() {

        binding.homeRv.adapter = homeRvAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
            header = HomeLoadStateAdapter { homeRvAdapter.retry() },
            footer = HomeLoadStateAdapter { homeRvAdapter.retry() },
        )

        homeRvAdapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            binding.homeRv.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            binding.shimmerLayout.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.tvHomeSearch.isInvisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.filterIv.isInvisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            binding.retryBtn.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Error
            handleError(loadState)
        }

        binding.retryBtn.setOnClickListener {
            homeRvAdapter.retry()
        }
    }

    private fun handleError(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
        val errorStates = loadState.source.append as? LoadState.Error
            ?: loadState.source.prepend as? LoadState.Error

        errorStates?.let {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "${it.error}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

    private fun setUpHomeRv() {
        homeRvAdapter = HomeRvAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            homeRv.adapter = homeRvAdapter

            homeRvAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy =
                RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY

            homeRv.addItemDecoration(DefaultItemDecorator(
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.horizontal_margin),
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.vertical_margin)
            ))
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong. I'm not having any errors and the data is showing correctly but it doesn't change after filtering. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: source code 
https://github.com/ElmarShkrv/ChioreRickAndMorty

Comment: i don't have any errors the data is showing correctly but it doesn't change after filtering

Comment: Your ViewModel implementation for paging data is not correct. Please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging-basics#0) and make changes accordingly

Comment: but this way i have to put string for filtration inside Repository.
I can already get the paging data, without filtering